# Can we create Sitemap for private routes in react application?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sitemap, sitemap.xml

I have created a Sitemap.xml file in my react application using react-router-sitemap package from npm.
I'm new to this SEO and Google search console, it got an indexing error in GSC. that's y I created the sitemap.
I've  created sitemap file using the public routes in my site, but I'm not sure if we need to include private routes. I'm almost 100% sure that private routes cannot / shouldn't be crawled by google bots but wanted to make sure.

Comment: A route is a mapping between a URLs and handler code.  You can't put "routes" into a sitemap, but you can list URLs handled by routes.

Comment: Sitemaps have almost no SEO benefit.  At best they can get Googlebot to crawl your URLs.  However they don't help get your pages indexed or ranked well.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: What is the purpose of your private routes? What makes them private? Do they require login?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.

Comment: Yes the private routes requires user to login

Comment: Great, include that information in the question when you ask on Webmasters.  It should be easy for somebody to answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitemap shouldn't include private routes. Even if you include them it is of no use.